# .each only working on 1st selectbox

Tags: jquery, html

Basically, when trying to utilise the `each` function in jQuery I'm bumping into a problem which I can't seem to get past,

Here's the jQuery code I'm attempting to use :

```
$('#status_update').each(function(index) {
        alert(this);
        $(this).on('change', function (e) {
            alert('changed');
        });
});
```

Here's the **HTML** code I'm using :

```
<select name='status_update[]' class='input input-medium' id='status_update' data-id='1'>
    <option value='0' selected>Not Admitted</option>
    <option value='1'>Admitted</option>
</select>

<select name='status_update[]' class='input input-medium' id='status_update' data-id='1'>
    <option value='0' selected>Not Admitted</option>
    <option value='1'>Admitted</option>
</select>
<select name='status_update[]' class='input input-medium' id='status_update' data-id='1'>
    <option value='0' selected>Not Admitted</option>
    <option value='1'>Admitted</option>
</select>

etc....
```

It works for the first one, but after that it doesn't activate the `on.change()` in the jQuery which results in it not processing.

Comment: `id='status_update'` on three elements - can't be helpful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[id should be unique in a document](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute), you have multiple element with the same id.

You can use a common class for all the element and use the class selector instead of id selector

```
$('.status_update').each(function(index) {
        alert(this);
        $(this).on('change', function (e) {
            alert('changed');
        });
});
```

Comment: @Curtis in that case you need to change the select box generation logic, because it is plain wrong to have multiple elements with same id

Answer (score 1):

An ID should only be applied to a *single* element. Try using .input-medium as your jquery selector, i.e:

```
$('.input-medium').each(function(index) {
    alert(this);
    $(this).on('change', function (e) {
        alert('changed');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not assign same id for multiple elements, so better to remove id and use class

Answer (score 0):

If elements are dynamically generated, there are two workaround to this:

First: use jQuery live function [deprecated], use jQuery on instead

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Second: upon creation of the element, add the onchange with it.
example:

```
val jQel = $("<select name='status_update[]' class='input input-medium' data-id='1'>
    <option value='0' selected>Not Admitted</option>
    <option value='1'>Admitted</option>
</select>");
$(jQel).find(".input").change(function(){
 //add code here
});
//then your append code somewhere
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
$('input[id="status_update"]').each(function(index) {
        alert(this);
        $(this).on('change', function (e) {
            alert('changed');
        });
});
```